# Unit Testing in Asp.Net MVC project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc

I am a newbie to write a unit testing please provide the guidance on what is the unit test for  the following simple structure which may be passed in TestResult in VS 2019???

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the shown example, inspect the view result to assert the expected behavior when `About` is invoked.

A very simplified example

```
[TestMethod]
public void AboutTest() {
    //Arrange
    var controller = new MyController();
    string expected = "Put expected message here";

    //Act
    var result = controller.About() as ViewResult;
    var actual = (string) result.ViewData["Message"];

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

The `ViewBag` data can be extracted from the `ViewResult.ViewData` collection as shown above.

Note the use of the matching name of the dynamic property set in the controller action.

Comment: Thanks for your help,,,,
Please elaborate your Note Point.. I didnt get it properly

Comment: @DevenThakur In your example a `Message` is set on the `ViewBag`. In the test `"Message"` is extracted from the `ViewData` of the result to be used when doing the assertion that the subject under test behaves as expected when exercised.

Comment: will you please help me on the following also. I am returning a page with employee list which is binded from the database on List<> variable.
public ActionResult EmployeePage()
 {
            MVCTutorialsEntities db = new MVCTutorialsEntities();
            List<Employee> employeeList = db.Employees.ToList();    
            List<EmployeeView> empViewList = employeeList.Select(x => new EmployeeView  {  Id = x.Id,  Name = x.Name, Address = x.Address, DepartmentId = x.DepartmentId,DepartmentName = x.Department.DepartmentName}).ToList();
            return View(empViewList);
        }

Comment: May I have your Direct Messaging on which I can learn unittesting with you... Please

Comment: Please would you  like to tell me the same testing code with ASP.NETCORE with XUnit Testing methods.